# Installation problem when running Ubuntu from CD

Tags: installation, resolution

I have tried to run Ubuntu from a CD. It has loaded with 4 screens and seems to be the wrong resolution for my laptop.

I have mouse control but cannot click on anything to try and resolve this problem.

Can you advice please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to burn the cd again at a slow speed. Or try to boot from a USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

Along with burning a new CD or using a USB stick, try getting the `.iso` from a different source. I have problems with anything but the direct download from Ubuntu.com on my Dell laptop. Others have experienced similar install issues with 12.04 on specific hardware.